# IOS - UIImagePickerController - Constrain the proportions of an image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I have setup a simple photo capture system to capture a profile pic within an IOS app, all works fine apart from I dont understand how to constrain the proportions of the image to suit the 120px x 120px profile image frame.

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

The UIview looks as follows - 
[image]

My code is as follows -

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender {
     if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
     UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
    [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType =
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker
                       animated:YES completion:nil];
    _newMedia = YES;
   }


}

- (IBAction)editPicBtn:(id)sender {
    [_cameraPanel setHidden:NO];


 }

 -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
    UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    _photoSquare.image = image;

    if (_newMedia)
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,
                                       self,

                                               @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                       nil);
}
else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
{
    // Code here to support video if enabled
}
[_cameraPanel setHidden:YES];

}

-(void)image:(UIImage *)image
 finishedSavingWithError:(NSError *)error
 contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    if (error) {
      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle: @"Save failed"
                          message: @"Failed to save image"
                          delegate: nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
      [alert show];
 }
}

 -(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
 {
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }

- (IBAction)useCameraRoll:(id)sender {
   if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
     UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
   {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
    [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType =
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker
                       animated:YES completion:nil];
    _newMedia = NO;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2):

When selecting an image from the camera roll, there is an option to scale/position the picture so that user can take a square cropping of an existing photo. You can then resize the square picture to your desired 120x120 px image. I am not sure if this option is available also for freshly taken photos, but I would guess so.

If Apple's standard cropping tool is not enough, you can always implement your own. And this is what I did.

```
// Hides the controls for moving & scaling pictures, or for
// trimming movies. To instead show the controls, use YES.
imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
```

The cropper returns square image of 640x640 px, so to resize the image to 120x120 px you can do:

```
- (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 240.0, 240.0); // 240.0 rather then 120.0 for retina
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    [image drawInRect:rect];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Martin - the editor works fine and constrains the image to square proportions on camera roll - but squashes the image for live camera..

Comment: What do you mean by squashes the image..? I tried it myself and it's working fine. The allowsEditing  = YES was enough to present the cropper for both UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera and UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary sourceTypes and both pictures were cropped to squares in my case.